# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

This is my query to find maximum and minimum salary employees, below:

```
create or replace procedure Minmax 
( H_EMP_NO OUT EMP.EMPNO%TYPE, L_EMP_NO OUT EMP.EMPNO%TYPE) 
IS
BEGIN
 SELECT EMPNO INTO H_EMP_NO FROM EMP
 WHERE SAL = (SELECT MAX(SAL) FROM EMP);

 SELECT EMPNO INTO L_EMP_NO FROM EMP
 WHERE SAL = (SELECT MIN(SAL) FROM EMP);
END minmax;


DECLARE
 H_EMP_NO EMP.EMPNO%TYPE;
 L_EMP_NO EMP.EMPNO%TYPE;
 H_SAL EMP.SAL%TYPE;
 L_SAL EMP.SAL%TYPE;

BEGIN

Minmax(H_EMP_NO, L_EMP_NO);

SELECT SAL INTO H_SAL FROM EMP
WHERE EMPNO = H_EMP_NO;

SELECT SAL INTO L_SAL FROM EMP
WHERE EMPNO = L_EMP_NO;


DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(H_EMP_NO || ' HAVE MAXIMUM SALARY = ' || H_SAL);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(L_EMP_NO || ' HAVE MINIMUM SALARY = ' || L_SAL);

END;
```

I remember i run the same query a few days back, and it was working fine, but now it says
**PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE"**

A point i would like to mention i've tried using **/ symbol** before **Declare** but then it says:
**PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/"**

Comment: Those seem to be a procedure and an anonymous block, not queries.

Comment: In PL/SQL Developer, you should open procedure code in a Program Window, and save it as a .prc file or some other agreed extension (configurable in the preference settings). You can use a Test Window for anonymous blocks, and save these with a .tst extension.

Answer (score 2):

Put a slash between

```
END minmax;
/                    --> this

DECLARE
```

Because, when you "serially" run several PL/SQL procedures, they have to be terminated, somehow - and that's a slash.

Or, if you create a procedure first, do so (either by removing everything else, or - possibly - by selecting (you know, "making it blue" with a mouse) that piece of code and running only it. Then execute anonymous PL/SQL block (again - by selecting it, or by removing the procedure).

---

To illustrate it: your code, unchanged. All I added are slashes in lines #11 (first code) and #22 (second code):

```
SQL> create or replace procedure Minmax
  2  ( H_EMP_NO OUT EMP.EMPNO%TYPE, L_EMP_NO OUT EMP.EMPNO%TYPE)
  3  IS
  4  BEGIN
  5   SELECT EMPNO INTO H_EMP_NO FROM EMP
  6   WHERE SAL = (SELECT MAX(SAL) FROM EMP);
  7
  8   SELECT EMPNO INTO L_EMP_NO FROM EMP
  9   WHERE SAL = (SELECT MIN(SAL) FROM EMP);
 10  END minmax;
 11  /

Procedure created.

SQL> DECLARE
  2   H_EMP_NO EMP.EMPNO%TYPE;
  3   L_EMP_NO EMP.EMPNO%TYPE;
  4   H_SAL EMP.SAL%TYPE;
  5   L_SAL EMP.SAL%TYPE;
  6
  7  BEGIN
  8
  9  Minmax(H_EMP_NO, L_EMP_NO);
 10
 11  SELECT SAL INTO H_SAL FROM EMP
 12  WHERE EMPNO = H_EMP_NO;
 13
 14  SELECT SAL INTO L_SAL FROM EMP
 15  WHERE EMPNO = L_EMP_NO;
 16
 17
 18  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(H_EMP_NO || ' HAVE MAXIMUM SALARY = ' || H_SAL);
 19  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(L_EMP_NO || ' HAVE MINIMUM SALARY = ' || L_SAL);
 20
 21  END;
 22  /
7839 HAVE MAXIMUM SALARY = 5000
7369 HAVE MINIMUM SALARY = 800

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: The error still says: **PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/"**

Comment: I edited the answer and added an example which shows that it *works*; have a look, please.

Comment: I've tried doing with selecting which means creating procedure only at first, and then executing the remaining block of the code which calls the function, it worked.

Comment: Right; just as I said.